Gas Expansion Resolution
Is this resolution wrong?

Since the value of Wad is -4.68 KJ, applying this value to the expression ln(pi/pf) should yield a positive result of 0.750 instead of -0.750, correct? This is due to the minus sign in the equation.

$\Delta T = 300~ \mathrm{K} - 450~ \mathrm{K}$

I believe the person who solved this problem included a negative sign in front of the first equation (ΔU = nCpΔT) because they used the temperatures in reverse order during their calculations. However, my point is that when they used the expression -(-W/nRT), it resulted in a positive value of 0.750 instead of -0.750 because the work is negative and the equation naturally has a negative sign.

OK, I see about the sign.

Yes, I agree it is +0.750.

It is a simple math check that logarithm of number greater than 1 cannot be negative. You have had too big respect for the source of the task.

No, no. The final result is positive. The negative aspect of the question comes from the division of -(-W/nRT), where we should apply the exponential function. For example, e^ln(pi/pf) = e^(-0.75), allowing us to calculate pf. My main point is that the correct expression should be e^0.75 instead of e^(-0.75).

as pi > pf, ln{pi/pf) > 0, so not equal to -0.75.
